# What is a good way of tracking a variable size subset of a large variable size vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

As part of a simulation I'm currently iterating through a large vector of objects looking for those that have an attribute. It seems to me that it would be faster to store the addresses of those objects in another vector of pointers until I no longer need to operate on them... example code would looks like this... I'm not sure about the erase part.

```
public:
    bool studying = false;
    void study();
};
void student::study()
{
    //Read a book
    studying = false;
};

int vector_question_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<student> masterList;
    std::vector<student*> studyingList;

    student lazy1;
    student good1;
    good1.studying = true;

    student* s = &masterList.at(1);
    studyingList.push_back(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < studyingList.size(); i++)
    {
        studyingList.at(i)->study();
        if (studyingList.at(i)->studying == false)
        {
            studyingList.erase(i);
        }
    }


}
```

Am I on the right track or is there a "better" way? To help define my situation I won't know in advance how many objects I have or how many I need to track. I will need to iterate over and operate on them allot.

Edit:
Thanks for the initial responses.

@PaulMcKenzie
The hard requirements/statements of qualities I need from my collection of objects so far is that...

- it's easily re-sizeable due to wanting to add/remove objects
  frequently.
- I can iterate over the collection (in no particular order) performing
  some action such as getting/setting an attribute or calling a method.
- A objects method will only perform some action on its own attributes
  based on its own attributes or parameters.

I expect a future requirement will be that I want to only iterate over a smaller subset. prematurely optimising. Thanks @Jack Deeth

Comment: If that `masterList` gets resized in some way, those pointers you stored become invalidated.  Don't store pointers to items in a vector.  If you want to store pointers to items, have `masterList` be a `std::list`, not a vector.  Also, [don't erase items in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020726/vector-erase-error-c2664/23021025#23021025)

Comment: Also, when you iterate in a vector for removing, dont increment the index `i` when you remove. Even better use the `erase/remove_if` idiom.

Comment: Also, post the entire `student` class.  Maybe a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` is all you need, and not need to have pointers to items.

Comment: Iterating over an array of contiguous objects is fast. Dereferencing an array of pointers is not fast. I'd recommend you don't prematurely optimise!